# How to do a row-wise COUNTIF, grouping by date

Tags: vba, do-while

Here's a simplification of my data. I have these events occurring by date. The "x" marks the day each event occurred.

[image]

What I'm doing is counting how many events happened in each month, using `COUNTIF()`. So I have something like:

[image]

The problem is: I use one `COUNTIF()` for each month and it can be very tricky when you have, let's say, 50 months.

How can I resolve this with VBA? If wasn't separated by date would be easy, but I haven't able to solve this.
I appreciate it if someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a Pivot Table to group by month-end and count the records.

https://trumpexcel.com/group-dates-in-pivot-tables-excel/

https://www.myexcelonline.com/blog/group-month-excel-pivot-tables/

[image]

[image]

If you need to do this frequently, you can record a Macro, save it, and run it whenever you need it.